# Number of combinations of 1,2,3 that can achieve a number n

Tags: combinations

Already Tried Part :
The number of solutions of the equation x +2y + 3z = n .Let F(n) be the no. of ways of getting the solution . So , F(n) = F(n-3) + floor(n/2) + 1 . Tht's what i got from x+ 2y + 3z' = n -3 . For the case ,(z =0 ) x + 2y = n .We get , floor(n/2) + 1 solutions. I am not able to reach at a general value for f(n)
EXAMPLE : 8 can be expresses as 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1 , 1+1+1+1+1+1+2 , 1+1+1+1+2+2 , 1+1+2+2+2, 2+2+2+2 , 1+1+1+1+1+3 , 1+1+3+3 , 1+2+2+3 , 2+3+3 , 1+1+3+3 This is the series

Comment: You want us to give you the proof?

Comment: Yes ... I got it on searching from the net . But wasn't able to get the proof

Comment: That's not how this site works. Read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), and also take a look at http://whathaveyoutried.com.

Comment: sorry if i have violated any of the rules ... i will be careful the next time around

Comment: I tried to get the number of solutions of the equation x +2y + 3z = n  .Let F(n) be the no. of ways of getting the solution . So , F(n) = F(n-3) + floor(n/2) + 1 . Tht's what i got from  x+ 2y + 3z' = n -3 . For the case ,(z =0 ) x + 2y = n .We get , floor(n/2) + 1 solutions. I am not able to reach at a general value for f(n)

Answer (score 0):

Don't fully understand this sequence, just some links that may help you to find out the answer:

http://oeis.org/A008724

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molien_series

Comment: 8 can be expresses as 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1 , 1+1+1+1+1+1+2 , 1+1+1+1+2+2 , 1+1+2+2+2, 2+2+2+2 , 1+1+1+1+1+3 , 1+1+3+3 , 1+2+2+3 , 2+3+3 , 1+1+3+3  This is the series